# DB connection pool expired, then what?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, playframework, connection-pooling, c3p0

After my connection pool expires, when I try to open more connections in parallel than my max number of allowed connections in the pool, then I start getting timeout exceptions when trying to obtain a connection from the pool.

That is expected, however, the pool seems to be left in that state, where everything else I do since that moment gets the same timeout exceptions. As if each of the connections in the pool had been left busy, and can't be reused. I would expect the connections to get freed up over time, and then other connections being allowed, but this is not happening.

I'm using Play 1.2.5 with a jdbc driver to mysql, and from the logs I reckon the pool is C3P0.

I'm not explicitly closing the connections, since I believe is the right thing to do when using a pool, but I'm not 100% sure.

I don't know if this could be a connection leak in one of the framework/libraries I'm using, or if I'm doing something wrong or not doing something I should.

When I catch one of the timeout exceptions, what is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 2):

You **must** explicitly **close** connections when you use a connection pool. A connection pool has a collection of physical connections to a database. When you request a connection from the pool, it marks that physical connection as *in-use* and hands you a logical handle to that connection. This logical handle essentially is a wrapper or proxy which forwards most method calls (either directly or with some modification) to the physical connection.

When you call `close()` on this logical handle, the connection pool gets a signal that the physical connection is *available* again (that is: can be returned to the pool), the logical handle will from then on behave as a closed connection, but the actual physical connection is still open. If you don't call `close()`, the connection pool never gets this signal so the physical connection will remain *in-use* and won't be available for re-use.

Some advanced pool configurations allows the pool to detect this situation (eg using a timeout, or maybe with finalizers etc) and reclaim the connection, but you should **not** depend on that.

**TL;DR:** Always call `close()` on your connection when you are done with it, whether it comes from a connection pool, a non-pooled `DataSource` or `DriverManager`.

Comment: when my connection max was 10, I had the app running without problems using more than 10 connections, although not in parallel, so, not closing them explicitly, they were being reused. Maybe that timeout you mention? I started off by closing the connections, but that was giving me problems, exceptions saying that I was trying to use connections that were closed.

Comment: @palako If you are actually needing more than the max number of connections at the same time it is logical that you either get an errors or are blocked until a connection becomes available (depends on the pool config). Closing connections as soon as possible should alleviate that, because the physical connection becomes available sooner, than when the pool has to detect that. If you get errors now when closing, then the pool is not conforming to the JDBC spec, because a pooled connection should look and act like a normal connection (including behavior of `close()`)

Comment: I think I had some concepts messed up. I'm tidying up my code now closing resultSets and PreparedStatements, but not connections, and working so far, but haven't finished, and want to give it a try closing the connections as well to come out of this one learning something.